# Scala macro refactoring

Tags: scala, macros

I have written JDBC select and insert mapping using scala macro functionality.

[gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7e3ff45a6382f12f013cb7ed16001400#file-jdbcmapping-scala)

As you can see in the gist there is a lot of duplicated code...
I can't extract case classes ClassInfo and ColumnInfo outside of method scope because of c.universe._ import because I'm using c.Type.

I have tried using scala.reflect.runtime.universe._ but then I get some mirror exceptions and suddenly type comparison doesn't work anymore - I don't get ClassSymbol anymore but SynchronizedClassSymbol and I have to compare it using fullName and it suddenly get's very messy...

So my question is:

I would like to refactor:

```
case class ClassInfo
case class ColumnInfo
mapGet
mapSet
def getBaseClass(tp: c.Type): c.Type
def getClassInfo(tp: c.Type): Option[ClassInfo]
def getConstructorParameters(tp: c.Type): Seq[ColumnInfo]
def selectFullTermName(sym: c.Symbol): c.Tree
```

Outside of methods selectImpl and insertImpl but I just don't know how :(
I tried for example with method

```
def getBaseClass(tp: c.Type): c.Type
```

To put it outside like this:

```
  def getBaseClass(c: whitebox.Context)(tp: c.Type) = {
    import c.universe._
    if (tp.baseClasses.map(_.fullName).contains(symbolOf[Option[_]].fullName))
      tp.typeArgs.head
    else
      tp
  }
```

But then where I call it like

```
getBaseClass(c)(x.typeSignature)
```

I get an error:

```
Type missmatch, expected: c.Type, actual: whitebox.Context#Type
```

And it drives me crazy =)

I'm quite new at Scala so if you have any other comments about how to write macros - if I have made any mistakes - please let me know=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it works like this:

```
def getBaseClass(c: whitebox.Context)(tp: c.Type) = {
  import c.universe._
  if (tp.baseClasses.map(_.fullName).contains(symbolOf[Option[_]].fullName))
    tp.typeArgs.head
  else
    tp
}
```

It compiles but IntelliJ reports error:

```
Type missmatch, expected: c.Type, actual: whitebox.Context#Type
```

So it's a IDE bug =)